# Apply formula to several values seperated by comma

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Would it be any simple way to apply a formula to several values separated with comma ?

Something like :

| Input data | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | https://some-url.com/15 |
| 12,15 | https://some-url.com/12, https://some-url.com/15 |

EDIT :

In deed, my question was ambiguous. The formula I wish to apply to several parameter is HYPERLINK. I would like something like that :

| Input data | Raw formula | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | HYPERLINK("http://some-url.com/A2";"A2) | [15](http://some-url/15) |
| 12,15 | ??? | [12](http://some-url/12), [15](http://some-url/15) |

Comment: What kind of formula?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 or Excel for the web, then I would start with the `Textsplit` function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the same URL for everything, you can achieve this with `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
="http://someurl.com/" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",", http://someurl.com/")
```

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But I didn't realize this wouldn't result in an actual hyperlink on excel (yeah I am total beginner). I have updated my question to explain what I would like more clearly.